# Use INDEX/MATCH to select formula written as string, and enable it?

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, evaluate

I have a pricelist, with currently 5 different categories of products. Each product will have to have two different prices. Depedning of the product and the type of price, the calculation will be different. Therefor I've used INDEX/MATCH to find the formula needed, from a table I created.

Below a screendump, and I wanted to attach the Excel fil, but canøt seem to work out how.
[image]

Question: HOW do I then "run" the formula I fetched? -I've tried different suggestions on using EVALUATION, but it doesn't seem to cut it? Also I've tried "Indirect' on the whole formula, without success.

I would like to avoid any VBA for this case.

Can anybody provide some insight?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* but if I understand properly, the only thing changing in the formulas is the "muliplier" number, then it's better to lookup that number instead of the whole formula.  The other method (which would use `Evaluate` etc) is not be considered "good practice" for a number of reasons.

---

### EDIT:

I didn't see the 2nd varying value (since I was on the SO mobile app) but it's still not an issue since it would a target column.  You could be thinking of the opposite: sometimes lookups based on multiple criteria can get complicated, but this a matter of more data, as opposed to adding **criteria** for the lookup.

`VLookup` would have been the simplest method, like G2 could have been:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2, $J$4:$L$8, 2, False)
```

...to return the second column of range `J4:L8` where the first column equals `E2`. (Then for the next required column, same formula except with 3 instead of 2.)

Since I wasn't sure more columns could be added one day, I allowed for that by, instead of specifying "Column 2 or 3" etc, it finds the column dynamically by name. (So the multiplier/factor used in G2 will change if you change the title in G1 to the name of a different column existing in the target data chart.

For the sake of neatness as well as potential of additional columns like G & H, I moved the lookup table to a separate sheet.  It can stay out of the way since you won't need to see or change it very often.   (If the same chart was going to be referenced by many workbooks, you could even move it to a separate workbook and point all formulas at that, since it's always best to have one copy of identical data instead of many in different workbooks.

Also to assist with potential future changes (and just to be tidier), instead of referring to the target table range addresses (like "J4:L8" etc) I named two ranges:

- the table of multiplier/factor data can be referred to by it's address, or by `myMultipliers`
- the titles of the same table is also called `myMultiplierTitles` (used to match to the titles of column G & H on the original sheet.

### Formula

After those changes, the lookup formula in G2 is:

```
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP($E2,myMultipliers,MATCH(G$1,myMultiplierTitles,0),FALSE)&ROW())*VLOOKUP($E2,myMultipliers,MATCH(G$1,myMultiplierTitles,0)+1,FALSE)
```

`INDIRECT` returns the value of a cell that you refer to by name (text/string) as opposed to directly (as a range).  For example:

```
=INDIRECT("A1")
```

returns the same as

```
=A1
```

...but with `INDIRECT` we can get the name from elsewhere (a cell, function or formula).  So if x="A1" then =INDIRECT(x) returns the same as the 2 above examples.

Your original plan of storing the entire formula in a table as text would have worked with the help of `INDIRECT` and/or `EVALUATE` but I think this way is considered better practice partly because it facilitates easier future expansion.

The formula is *longer* than it would have been, but that's mostly because it's dynamically reading the field names.  And size doesn't matter.  :-)

[image: ex1]

[image: ex2]

Comment: The problem is, that it is not only the multiplier, but also the column which will have the figure that will be multiplied.

You can see that indicated as B and C (and potentially a couple of more, in the final sheet)

That's why I don't think it will be sufficient with lookup...

Comment: ok, I see that now that I'm not looking at this site on my phone.  :-)  2 values are not an issue.  I'll add to my answer now to show why.

Comment: question to confirm i understand: For example, anything with Category `BTB+KO` needs to get the values of `INDIRECT("C",ROW())*2` and `INDIRECT("B",ROW())*2.5)`, correct?

Comment: Mail sent - you can delete comment!

Thanks!

Comment: Correct! -And I need to be able to change these factors/column numbers.

Comment: yes no problem. and it's always looking up based on one column.  VLookup is the simplest option when looking up based on only one value.  Example in a few mins :)

Comment: besides changing the existing multiplier/factor, will you need ability to add more columns besides 'New Price BTB` and `New Price BTC' (on the right-side)? or will those be the only 2

Comment: There will only be those two columns where new prices will be calculated.

Comment: ok well the one I sent back allows for expansion since I wasn't sure, but it's moved to a 2nd sheet so it's out of the way anyway.  You could delete the unneeded columns and make the formulas on the first sheet shorter (since the `MATCH` portion of the formula would be unnecessary), but it will work just fine as i (and, future expansion is hard to predict, "just when you think you know everything" is when curve-balls start coming... haha).  The 2nd tab sheet can also be hidden or moved to a different workbook if need be.

Comment: did you get the email back?

Comment: This link is not _directly_ related to your question but I recommended it to someone else and I think you'd also find value from checking out: **[Chip Pearson's 600+ copy-and-paste solutions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/topic.aspx)**; there's something there to benefit every Excel project and boost your skill level along the way.  I call him the _King of Excel_.   

Comment: Hey!

This looks JUST RIGHT! -Wow, really impressed...!

Could you send me the raw file, by chance?
There's stuff to learn, in this great answer! :)

Comment: PS. Trying to give you credit for the answer, but as I'm new - apparently, it doesn't "count"?